# Filter list and its children in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, bootstrap-4

This is my html code:

```
<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<ul class="list-group" id="myList" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="list-group-item">
         <h1>b - B</h1>
    </li>
    <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
         <h3>backbiting</h3>
             <div class="card">
                 <div class="card-body text-left">
                      <div class="card-text"><p>Loreum Ipsum</p></div>
                 </div>
             </div>
    </li>
```

This is the jquery I am using:

```
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList h3").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
});
```

I want search/filter to work on li > h3 element and the above code is working but I am not able to hide cards under every list. How should I do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are you are getting problem in hiding the li also along with h3.
Here, you have select only #myList h3 so only that segment will be hide on filter. To hide li along with that you have to select both the elements i.e., parent of that element. So, instead of select #myList h3 select #myList li and in filter use $(this).find('h3').text() for filter like below...

```
$("#myInput").keyup(function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myList li").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).find('h3').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
```

I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: If I do that then the filter works on the <div class="card-text"> and I only want to filter text enclosed inside <h3>. So a word enclosed inside  <div class="card-text"> is also presented when search is used. I only want to filter words enlosed inside <h3>